# Gulp/Grunt folder Structure and Practices for PHP Projects

Tags: javascript, php, gruntjs, yeoman, gulp

I'm learning Gulp and I'm wondering how to use it in a typical project
I have a Laravel project with a public folder that has a /js folder that holds all my javascript files..

Now for the live server I would like to minify them, I have gulp-minify working but how do you arrange the folder structure? Any idea's on a good practice to do this?

### Method 1: Concat all javascript files into one

*So the idea is to concat all the javascript files into 1 javascript file and include that.*

My question here is: I have a lot of page-specific javascript, Like my homepage has a slider which relies on a certain div with an ID, But on other pages that element isn't there, **so the elements necessary to make the javascript work aren't there, and the code isn't needed for that page?**

### On Topic

http://ryankent.ca/starting-a-new-project-with-laravel-5-gulp-bower-and-bootstrap/

I'm very interested in your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different approaches.

One is to have separate `/src` (for the source files) and `/build` (for the minified files) folders inside your `/js` folder. Another approach is to append `.min` to the minified files and keep them alongside your source files. A potential downside of these approaches is that you will have to update all references to your JavaScript files in your templates.

Lukasz's approach is probably the one I'd recommend, since it requires the least work. Ultimately, it's up to you and your personal preference.

Comment: Whats about node_module folder. I am recently start with gulp and bower. All things are good, but little confusion is handling folder structure for my site on local version and also for live version. Confusion is the node_module folder. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

You should do sth more than minifing files. You can merg all js files using concat.
It's usually better to load single file instead of 10 small files.

My recomendation is to minify and concat all files from js and put in level up - just in your public.

Comment: Well i have a lot of page-specific .js files, Like one page has an ajax update script, but the other page's don't need those 50 lines of code. Won't this method throw errors when the code is also executed without some elements being on the page

Comment: @Notflip: Yeah, it will. My understanding is that this method works best when you're using a framework, or your JavaScript is modular. For example, when using Backbone, you might concatenate all of your View files into a single file. On your 'login' page, you would just include `new LoginView({ el: element });` in your template to instantiate the view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Maybe i should include in the question that this is mainly for php projects ( using laravel )

Comment: @Notflip: No problem. I should point out that you're not tied to any approach - you can combine modular/framework-oriented JS with 'traditional' web frameworks which render templates on the server (like Laravel).

Comment: That's the big search haha. Because i know laravel has a complicated folder structure, So i don't want to make it even more complicated with my frontend preprocessors. But i really want to start using gulp or grunt :)

Answer (score 0):

For page specific javascript you can use [gulp-htmlmin](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/gulp-htmlmin): it's born for html minification but it can also minimize your inline javascript calling uglify under the hood.